# Create a colorbar without a mappable in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

To call `plt.colorbar` I need a "mappable", which I usually create by `plt.imshow` or `plt.contour`. Is there a "reasonable" way to create a mappable without these?

More specifically, my code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import viridis

colors = viridis(np.linspace(0,1,10))
for i, col in enumerate(colors):
    plt.plot(i, 'o', color = col)
```

I would then like to call `plt.colorbar`, but I don't have a mappable.
My usual work around is `cmap = plt.scatter(np.linspace(0,1), np.full(50, np.nan), c = np.linspace(0,1))`, which works perfectly well, but I find utterly ugly.

Answer (score 3):

In that case, you can use `scatter` not only for generating the mappable, but doing all the job at once (plotting the dots, and returning the corresponding mappable).

**EDIT**

In general, Matplotlib always provides a way to make a collection of objects (see for instance the [LineCollection usage example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/shapes_and_collections/line_collection.html)) allowing to plot a collection of lines (or any other object) with varying properties like color, line width, etc.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

colors = np.linspace(0,1,10)
mappable = plt.scatter(np.zeros(10), colors, s=30, c=colors, cmap='viridis')
plt.colorbar(mappable)
plt.show()
```

Which produce the following image

[image: scatter mappable colorbar]

Comment: True for that case. I guess I simplified my code to much. In the actual code each iteration of the for loop generates a line. There might be a work around using contour, but that's to much brainwork.

Comment: I understand. Just to let you know that in general, Matplotlib always provides a way to make a mappable from a collection of objects (see [the documentation about collections](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/shapes_and_collections/line_collection.html)). I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [matplotlib doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html), `colorbar` accepts a `ColorMappable` object. So we can create such an object with `ScalarMappable` and `Normalize`:

```
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

colors = viridis(np.linspace(0,1,10))
for i, col in enumerate(colors):
    plt.plot(i, 'o', color = col)

cmappable = ScalarMappable(Normalize(0,1))
plt.colorbar(cmappable)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Using the above code I got the Error: ``TypeError: You must first set_array for mappable``. I included the line ``cmappable.set_array([0,1])`` before plt.colorbar(cmappable), this works fine, but not sure what's actually happening/whether this is the correct usage.